# ToolTip bluets CSS issue in Chrome and FireFox

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, extjs, cross-browser

When I added to toolTip for ExtJs Grid that view defiance in FIreFox and Chrome web browsers.

This my tooltip CSS

```
padding-left:12px;
display:block;
background:transparent no-repeat 2px 2px;
```

This bellow image show how FireFox and Chrome view tooltip. FireFox correctly view bluet for last line but chrome view without bluet padding for last line. How can i correct this bluet issue in Chrome

[image: View in tool tip FireFox]

[image: View in tool tip Chrome]]

Answer (score 0):

You need to set:

`list-style-position:outside;`

In your CSS, or alternatively tweak the `padding-left` or `text-indent` properties.

If you're doing a direct CSS override for Ext JS (looks like a validation tooltip) you'll need to target that list class directly.